# Where to store public user state in Meteor?

Tags: collections, meteor, state, denormalization

Suppose I have chatrooms as part of a Meteor app, and inside each chatroom the users should see who else is in the chatroom, as well as the number of users in all other chatrooms.

Where should I store the chatroom that each user is in? Should it be

- in the provided `Meteor.users` collection, as a property under each user?
- in the `Chatrooms` collection, as a list of users inside each chatroom?
- What's the right way to denormalize the data so that a user can see the number of people in other chatrooms without needing to get pushed all of those user records as well?

A related question: when should I store things in `Meteor.users()` as opposed to a separate collection containing documents of user IDs and rooms, such as `ChatroomParticipants`? i.e.:

```
{ user: "foo", room: "room 1" }
{ user: "bar", room: "room 2" }
```

Additionally, is there a way to set this up so that a user can be logged in to the same app from multiple windows and be in different rooms? That is, the rendering for a particular user does not depend on some global state that makes everything change across sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You should make it write on `Meteor.users` document in that case. The less you centralize read/write in only one document, the better, so it won't be a bottleneck. See how [meteor-presence](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-presence#advanced-usage) make it on the Advanced Usage.

Comment: Can you give a reference on why it's worse to centralize on one document?

Comment: Additionally, is there any difference between using `Meteor.users` and a separate `ChatroomParticipants` collection which contains records of users and their corresponding chatrooms?

Comment: I've seen once a Google video/slides explaining how to do a blog on GAE Datastore (their scalable NoSQL), but I can't find it. The second question is: You can do both, but you don't need to. It will be more difficult to know where to find things, because you have multiple collections. Imagine you will have more 2 attributes for users in the future. Are you going to create more two separate collections ? Hope this makes sense, because I don't know how to explain it here.

Comment: The problem is, if I store the chat room(s) for each user in the users collection, there is no simple query that I can do to to get the number of users in each chatroom. At least, it seems pretty inefficient compared to indexing a couple of fields in `ChatroomParticipants`.

Comment: Yes that's true. Maybe it's better ask that on meteor-talk or on irc channel.